# Why is my powershell Base64 String truncated to 36 characters?

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using PowerShell inside VSTS Build for querying the VSTS API. I'm using PAT for authentication.

However, I see it failing when I generate the Auth string. Here is my code inside

```
    $VstsAccessEmail = $Env:VstsAccessEmail 
    $VstsAccessToken = $Env:VstsAccessToken
    $pair = "${VstsAccessEmail}:${VstsAccessToken}"
    $base64 = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($pair))
    Write-Host $base64
```

If I see the outcome here, I see the first 36 characters of the actual auth string. I generated the string using Powershell on my machine and I get the entire 108 characters. I have hard-coded this for time being to test this like the following steps that follow the above code.

```
    $base641 = "a2FuZ2thbi5nb3N3YW1pQHVuaXN5cy5jb206cHh4b25oaHBlNmtjb3g3aTRhdHZxMzdoNms2ZnpuNHhyaWhyZ2ozdGZ3ejRlNmxxxxXXXX=="
    if($base64.length -ne 108){
        $base64 = $base641
    }
    Write-Host "base64 is: $base64 "
```

This works correctly. Initially, I thought it might be an issue with Writing to host. However, If I do invoke the RestMethod without updating with the hard-coded one, I get 401 Unauthorized.

Please help.

**UPDATE:**

I found the issue. I set the `VstsAccessToken` as a secret in the build variables. So the value is not coming through. making it unsecured works fine.

**Can someone help how this can be done keeping the token as a secret?**

**SOLVED**

Using $Env:variable does not allow to use the value when the variable is secret. However, passing it as a parameter to the PowerShell let the code read it, though the output to log is masked.

Comment: I think your problem is with how your are defining the string to be encoded.  What are the curly brackets for?  `"${VstsAccessEmail}:${VstsAccessToken}"`.  Try this:  `"$VstsAccessEmail\`:$VstsAccessToken"` - note the backtick before the colon.  If this doesn't help, take a look at the value in `$pair` as originally defined to make sure it is what you expect.

Comment: @boxdog The advised change did not have any effect. I am still seeing the same result.

Comment: Did you check that `$pair` is being correctly populated?  Possibly the environment variables are not correctly set.  It may also be worth reversing the incorrect encoding you get to see what was actually encoded - I'm not sure if any special characters in your input might be causing an issue.

Comment: In case of error in the formation of the pair, the result would have been different. The result of the base64 string is same for the first 36 characters. I believe, it is caused by something at the environment level.

Comment: It depends on the value of `$pair`, what's the value of `$pair`? Check it by outputting it (Write-Host).

Comment: You should post an answer instead of include the solution in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $Env:variable does not allow to use the value when the variable is secret. However, passing it as a parameter to the PowerShell let the code read it, though the output to log is masked.

Answer (score 0):

This section is definitely wrong. I see one thing that's definitely wrong, another that's possibly wrong.

```
$VstsAccessEmail = $Env:VstsAccessEmail 
$VstsAccessToken = $Env:VstsAccessToken
$pair = "${VstsAccessEmail}:${VstsAccessToken}"
$base64 = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($pair))
```

1. `$pair = "${VstsAccessEmail}:${VstsAccessToken}"` should be `$pair = ":${VstsAccessToken}"`. No email address is neccessary, just a colon and then the auth token.
2. `UTF8.GetBytes` *may* be wrong. I always use `ASCII.GetBytes`.

Comment: Thanks. If I provide the email address, it does not cause any error. I tried it and as in the code, I hard-coded the base64 key that I generated manually and it is working fine. My question is about how to get the complete key inside that code. UTF8 and ASCII are giving same result. And UTF8 is always a better option.